# Datepicker inside Table Body when Loading data using $.ajax()

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, json, webservice-client

When i am trying to add Datepicker inside Table Body using $.ajax() to load data from server , the datepicker inside table is successfully loaded after i use .append() in jquery but when i click the Datepicker ... nothing Datepicker Picker UI is show. Please see my code below pic...

[image: Jquery $.ajax() call webservice]

and output is below screenshot , the Datepicker are successfully rendered but when i click the date picker its not working.

[image: $.ajax() call webservice successfully load dates from Table body]

Pleae Help guys.

Thanks all.

Comment: Give different ids for date picker fields. for eg: id='datepicker_'+i where i is the loop variable

Comment: i already did that Sir Nishan , But its not working ...

Comment: First make sure that the date picker is working for your context. Create table row object and input object inside the loop and initialize date picker (inside the loop).

Comment: can you show me sample code of yours Sir @NishanSenevirathna

Comment: Your sample is work perfectly but when i trying to use this code into my code ... nothings happen ...

Comment: Please debug your code and see console logs(for Google chrome f12) and try to find out where the issue is exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find out exact issue of your code. Try something like this,

```
<html lang="us">
<head>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style>
body{
    font: 62.5% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
    margin: 50px;
}   
    </style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    for( var i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
    {
        var $tRow = $("<tr>");
        var $tRowData1 = $("<td>Test</td>");
        var $tRowData2 = $("<td>");
        var $datePicObj = $("<input type='text' id='datepicker_"+i+"' />");
        $tRowData2.append($datePicObj);
        $datePicObj.datepicker({});
        var $tRowData3 = $("<td>Test</td>");
        $tRow.append($tRowData1);
        $tRow.append($tRowData2);
        $tRow.append($tRowData3);
        $("#bodyInfo").append($tRow);
    }
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="bodyInfo" ></table>
</body>
</html>
```